# Why does an interactive command (git add -i) exit immediately?

Tags: bash, terminal, git

I've used git add interactive before -- nice little ascii GUI.

Today when I ran `git add -i`, it prints all the expected dialog, and then exits immediately. (screenshot below, bash in gnome terminal.)

If I open a new terminal and run `git add -i`, it works fine.

So perhaps the question really is -- **what state is that shell in? Can it be corrected?**

[image: Git add interactive exits immediately]

Comment: Are you running the same program(s) in both windows? (I.e., any environment variable changes?) Same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your environment got somehow messed up. Simplest way out: start a new window (where it works), and just close the messed up one.

If in sleuth mode, compare environment variables git may use (including PATH, EDITOR, PAGER). Most git commands are external executables run by a small wrapper. See what is being called in both cases (e.g. using strace). See what happens if you run the workhorse by itself. Check for any "extra verbose/debugging" flag.

The git folks are rewriting some of the script commands as C programs, or fooling around with other experimental features. See if you have set some configuration (in `.git/config`, via environment variable, for your account, globally) that might select not-so-mature alternatives.